# Custom fonts PaxA920 and PaxA910

Tags: java, android, printing, point-of-sale, pax

There is a application working with PAX A920 and PAX A910 devices. There is a change request to change the print slip more attractive way. Is there a way to use custom fonts?

I have tried by did not works for me.

```
try {
    printerTester.setFontPath("font/calibri_regular.ttf");
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Existing application font sizes changed by

```
printerTester.fontSet(EFontTypeAscii.FONT_8_16, EFontTypeExtCode.FONT_16_16);
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing on these devices is usually done using only the fonts that the printer has. And most printers only support one type of font.
This is because performance can be ensured and resources can be saved.

If you want to decorate the printed content, create a graphic image of the content yourself and print it.

Maybe, your device specs or SDK has information to help you do that.
Please examine these materials carefully.

Even if you don't have that information, most of them should have the ability to print graphics, so try to create your own based on those specifications.